# How to set the font color in a UITableView's section header?

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors, header, sectionheader

Is `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` the best way to adjust the font color in a UITableViewCell's header section?

I'd like to simply adjust the font color (ideally) without having to define a `UIView`. I'm especially reluctant to use the above method since the alignment of section headers has given me trouble in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: returns a UIView. You have to create a UIView, add an UILabel into the UIView, and adjust the font for the UILabel.

For example:

```
{
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc]   
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];
label.font = [UIFont systemOfFontWithSize:12];
....
return headerView;
}
```